# set OMP threads number for external DLL

Tags: c++, windows, openmp

We imported a third-party dynamic library in our process which uses OpenMP internally. We want to limit number of parallel threads to one for this DLL, and not affecting other potential OMP code outside DLL. According of [Intel documentation](https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-windows-developer-guide-techniques-to-set-the-number-of-threads), it has two ways:

1. Set OMP_NUM_THREADS environment variable.
2. Call omp_set_num_threads() at runtime.

First way clearly affects everything in my process. While I'm not sure whether second way could affect OMP setting to a restricted DLL? It's not clearly stated from the documentation.

Comment: The environment variables are only checked when the program starts, and if the DLL uses the `num_threads` clause it will be used instead of the one set by `omp_set_num_threads`.

Answer (score 0):

The usual rule of preference for OpenMP is to evaluate `OMP_NUM_THREADS` when the OpenMP runtime starts up and before it creates the first threads.  The effect of `omp_set_num_threads()` depends on where it is being called.

If the call is made from the sequential region, then it affects the *next* parallel region to be encountered (unless that region uses the `num_threads` clause to set a different number).  If the call is made from within a parallel region, then the effect is only for the thread calling and will affect a nested parallel region encountered by that thread (again no `num_threads` clause for this region plus `OMP_NESTED=true`).

So, you you want to avoid parallelism for the invoked DLL functions, you must call `omp_set_num_threads(1)` before each invocation of the DLL functions and restore the previous value after the call returns.